# Tamaño de la consola en C

Tags: c, consola, codeblocks

Soy nuevo en C, y estoy buscando la manera de que cuando compilo y ejecuto mi código, la consola aparezca maximizada, fullscreen para ver la ejecución y resultados del código.

Estuve buscando mucho pero no logro hacerlo. Me pueden ayudar por favor?

Estoy usando el IDE CodeBlocks, sobre Windows.

Comment: Puede que te sirva
[esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053554/running-a-c-console-program-in-full-screen/4053682).

Comment: [Esta función](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolewindowinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN) es la que estás buscando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su comentario! Voy a probar y luego les comento como me fue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola que tal espero te encuentres bien, para cambiar el tamaño de la consola en C, debes utilizar la función:

```
system ("mode con cols=64 lines=32");
```

donde "cols" son las columnas o el ancho de la pantalla y "lines" las filas o altura, además debes agregar la librería

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

así es como puedes cambiar el tamaño de la consola de una manera sencilla,  sin embargo esto se considera malo, ya que no es segura.

Una manera segura de hacer lo anterior, consiste en cambiar el búfer y el tamaño usando la función de la librería

```
#include <windows.h>
```

el cual es el siguiente:

```
int main(void)
{
  SMALL_RECT rect;
  COORD coord;
  coord.X = 150; // Definiendo X y
  coord.Y = 50;  // Y para el tamaño del búfer.

  rect.Top = 0;
  rect.Left = 0;
  rect.Bottom = coord.Y-1; // Altura para ventana
  rect.Right = coord.X-1;  // Ancho para ventana

  HANDLE hwnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hwnd, coord);       // Establece tamaño del búfer
  SetConsoleWindowInfo(hwnd, TRUE, &rect);       // Establece el tamaño de la ventana

  return 0;
 }
```

Pero debes tener en cuenta que la función `SetConsoleWindowInfo` falla si el rectángulo de la ventana especificado se extiende más allá de los límites del búfer de la pantalla de la consola.

Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mike! Voy a probar con todo lo que me han ayudado. Les comentare luego como funciono! Gracias.